# Material with very small Young's modulus

Tags: stresses, biomechanics, elastic-modulus

I'm looking for a material with a Young's modulus of less than 100 Pa. I've looked at elastomers, but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering SE. Can you please elaborate on the engineering problem you trying to solve? If can provide more specifics there it will increase your chances of receiving good responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking for an unrealistic material.  If you peruse the [engineering toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/young-modulus-d_417.html) you'll find that the Young's modulus of typical materials is measured in 10<sup>9</sup> Pa so the value you are asking for is 7 orders of magnitude smaller than typical materials.  Even the Young's modulus of the rubber in rubber bands is ~10<sup>7</sup> Pa.

Another simple thought experiment will convince you of how unreasonable such a material is.  The change in altitude required to change the pressure by 100 Pa is 10 meters which is about 3 building stories.  Since Young's modulus is defined by 
$$
\frac{\Delta \ell}{\ell}=\frac{P}{E},
$$
where $E$ is Young's modulus, the strain on your material would be 1 if you carried it from the top of a 3 story building to the ground floor.  This means that the material would compress to nothing from such a minor change in elevation.  Real materials would, of course, be well into the non-linear regime at that point.